# Make a hyperlink to a folder, not a file, in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hyperlink, arcgis-10.8

I am trying to have a hyperlink open a folder of files, not launch a specific file.  I have successfully made it open the file, but I just want it to open the folder the file is in within Windows Explorer.  Is this possible without Python?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just put the path to the directory in the attribute table.
[image]

Of course you need to set the hyperlinks field to the attribute that contains the file path.

[image]

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I have it set up as required and if I have a path with a filename at the end (ie. "AA001.las") and I hover my cursor over the info window field with the link I get the pointer turning to the link-click hand, and i can click and it opens the .las file.  However if i remove the filename and just leave the folder path, both with a "\" and without one at the end of the path, and do the same thing in the info window, my pointer does not turn into a link-click hand and does not do anything when I click it.

Comment: Odd.  Can you include the directory path in your post?  Have you tried renaming your normal.mxt, restarting ArcGIS and trying again?

Comment: "Q:\A&A\Haida Gwaii\2018\BB034.las" launches the las file, but if i just have "Q:\A&A\Haida Gwaii\2018\" or "Q:\A&A\Haida Gwaii\2018" nothing happens.

Comment: I haven't renamed/deleted normal.mxt in a while because I dread the re-setup of toolbars and template settings (grin).

Comment: I have nothing for you but I can confirm that spaces in the path are not a problem.  I also tried opening a directory on a network drive and that worked as well..."Z:\GISpublic" (a partition of a server).  Save the normal.mxt to a different name like old.mxt.  If that is not the root of your trouble you can rename old.mxt back to normal.mxt and save your toolbars.

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a spin and hopefully normal.mxt is not the problem and I can just revert and move on.  I also confirmed that the "&" in the pathname did not seem to be the issue by testing on a path without any special characters.  The mystery continues...

Comment: Tried swapping out the normal.mxt but no change, field still doesn't show in info window as a hyperlink without a file at the end of the folder path.